# Google Sheets QUERY returns non-matching records

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

In this workbook [1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p0iGJDPixnBEr-eKf3Mhco-P8rsHxZN3-zqEUvbA5RI/edit?usp=sharing) the second, "DMK Recent" sheet is populated by a query that returns two records that do not meet the [C > date'2019-12-16'] criterion. These are the last two rows on the sheet. To make things more mysterious, those records display values in the C "Date" field that *do not match the source data*.

If I reduce the size of the source data, only correctly selected records are returned. Is there some source data size beyond which the QUERY() function loses its grip? Many thanks for any light on this.

Answer (score 1):

your query formula:

```
=QUERY(xFRm!A5:X, 
 "select A,B,C,D,F,E,K,M,G,J 
  where C > date'2019-12-16' 
    and G='THB' 
  order by C,D", 1)
```

is is working flawlessly.

the culprits in your case are wrongly entered dates

[image: 0]

---

go and fix rows **4539** and **4540**

[image: 0]